# Use php to create a dynamic menu without a database using only folders in the directory?

Tags: php, html, tree

I would like to thank anyone who is able to help me in any way possible, I am extremely new to php/coding in general so I am not even sure if I am on the right path.

I wanted to know if it was possible to create 2 step or dynamic drop down menu using only php and html that populates the first drop down menu with folders from a directory.

So far I have

```
<?php
// Set the path of the dir you want displayed...
$path="./track";
$handle=opendir($path);
while ($file=readdir($handle))
{
    echo "\t<option value='".$file."'>".$file."</option>\n";
}
```

?>

This lets me grab the the folders from a directory, how would I proceed to create a second drop down menu that would let you choose any of the files from whichever folder you selected in the first drop down menu, and then display it on the website?

An example picture of what I am trying to achieve is as follows:
http://postimg.org/image/im03tjh0d/

Comment: Do you mean the second dropdown depends on the value of the first dropdown? Is that the problem?

Comment: Use ajax and file system functions.

Comment: Yeah, I want to try and make the second dropdown depend on the value of the first dropdown. I've gotten as far as creating 2 drop down menus. I can get the first one to return the files in a directory, but how do I get the second one to respond to that? 
For example: 
Select an Event:
Please select an Event first: 
I choose an event like say All-Star. Then it would display
All-Star
Select a Race: (Then letting me choose something from the directory the first folder is in)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? There are better solutions in newer versions of PHP that would be more efficient.

Comment: I think based on the web server suite version 1.95 Php 5.2.1

Comment: `glob()` + `basename()` is easier for simple dir scanning: `$files = array_map('basename', glob('path/to/files/*'));`

Comment: There are PLENTY of chained select questions on this site....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Check if we have submit the folder 
 * Check if we have submit the file
 */
$post_folder = isset($_POST['folder']) ? $_POST['folder']: null;
$post_file = isset($_POST['file_name']) ? $_POST['file_name'] : null; 

/**
 * Built out the Folder submission form
 */
// Set the path of the dir you want displayed...
$path="./";
echo '<form method="POST" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'">';
echo '<select name="folder">';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $asset){
    if($asset->isDot()) continue;
    if($asset->isDir()){
       /**
        * If we've posted which folder we want to view the contents of
        * then automatically make that selected in the dropdown on page load
        */
        $selected = (isset($post_folder) && $post_folder == $asset->getFileName()) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "\t<option value='".$asset->getFilename()."' $selected>".$asset->getFilename()."</option>\n";    
    }
}
echo '</select>';

if(isset($post_folder)){
    echo '<select name="file_name">';
    $folder_to_iterate = $path.$post_folder;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folder_to_iterate) as $asset){
        if($asset->isFile()){
           /**
            * If we've posted which folder we want to view the contents of
            * then automatically make that selected in the dropdown on page load
            */
            $selected = (isset($post_file) && $post_file == $asset->getFileName()) ? 'selected' : '';
            echo "\t<option value='".$asset->getFilename()."' $selected>".$asset->getFilename()."</option>\n";    
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

$btn_text = isset($post_folder) ? 'Show File Contents' : 'Show Folder Contents';
echo '<input type="submit" value="', $btn_text ,'"/>';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($post_file)){
    $file_to_read = $path.$post_folder.'/'.$post_file;
    echo '<pre>';
    echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($file_to_read));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm super grateful for your help you're a great person! Just one quick thing:
For the second drop down menu, when I select on something is there a way for it to open up automatically?

Comment: @user3071439 Check the updated answer, this should address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, you're a real lifesaver! 
I actually tried the updated code by now it seems to have taken away the second drop-down menu option, but I will try and play around with it to get it to work! Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: @user3071439 If this worked for you, please click the "Checkmark" next to the top of my question so mark it as "Accepted". You can also click the 'Up Arrow' as well.

Comment: I would upvote you, but I need more rep is what it says... but I clicked the checkmark! Thanks man

Comment: Hi again, I actually was having a small problem with this code, as of now it DOES work, however; when it tries to open up the pdf it returns... postimg.org/image/wpdidgrvl

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax and the file system functions.